# AngularJS $setvalidity MomentJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript, momentjs

I am using AngularJS TypeScript MomentJS to write a directive that validates if an input is in the write date format.

Following is the directive

```
declare function moment(x: any,y:any);

((): void => {
    'use strict';


    function validDate(): ng.IDirective {

        var directivedate = <ng.IDirective>{
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: true,
            link: link
        };


        function link(scope: ng.IScope, elm: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs, ctrl: ng.INgModelController) {


            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                dateFormat(viewValue);
            });
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                dateFormat(viewValue);
            });

            var dateFormat = function(viewValue) {



                var val = moment(viewValue, "DD/MM/YYYY").isValid();
                ctrl.$setValidity('validDate', val);




            }


        }

        return directivedate;

    }

    angular.module('validDate', []).directive('validDate', validDate);
})();
```

My problem here is that if i console.log val it is correct true or false but the $setvalidity is not working like at all.

Any ideas on why that might be.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use $parsers and $formatters to do that. Use a validator. That's what they're for: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators

Comment: Its still not working here goes a pln [link][http://plnkr.co/edit/vvq0QbYkyIM05K3FS7o9?p=preview/link] to clarify the problem

Comment: Fixed that for you: you forgot to define a form named myForm, and the validator is just supposed to return true or false to tell whether the value if valid or not. Angular does everything else for you. http://plnkr.co/edit/p9R3l9IBatpDv5t1Zpof?p=preview

Comment: Thanks mate worked brilliantly